# Закрытие текущего блока и открытие следующего

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток, помогите разобраться с скриптом он действует только раз(
а блоков 6

```js
 $(".next").click(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $(".setting").eq(i).fadeOut();
  $(".setting").eq(++i).fadeIn();
  $(".back").click(function() {
   $(".setting").eq(i).fadeOut();
   $(".setting").eq(--i).fadeIn();
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Cricket, зачем тут `each`?

Comment: @MedvedevDev, пардон, перепутал..